# Ribbon X changes via XML - disabling an addIn

Tags: excel, xml, office-addins, powerpivot, ribbonx

[image]I want to hide the "**Power Pivot**" menu item for a specific document.  (the reason - When I sent it out, I don't want users to have the ability to go into "manage measures...")

I know how to use the customUI14.xml to hide menu items such as home, data

```
<tab idMso="TabHome" visible="false"/>  
<tab idMso="TabData"  visible="false"/>
```

I did find out that the Power Pivot is not a built in Excel menu item.

It is part of the "Application.COMAddIns" collection and called "Microsoft Power Pivot for Excel".

However, I didn't find any way to disable it or make it invisible with the ribbonX XML,  the same easy way as we would disable a Home or Data tab.  Any ideas?

Is there a way to disable an add-in through the XML?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A screenshot of the control which you would like to hide would be a plus for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two main ways to find the control's `idMso` value:

1. The straightforward way is to search for the control ID in [the list of controls IDs](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-fluent-ui-command-identifiers).
2. Another possible solution is to search for the required control in the Excel options dialog:

   [image: options dialog in excel]

   Where you could hover over any control from the list and check its ID in the popup window.

Comment: Thanks Eugene.
I tried both: In the menu i didn't find it. In the mouse hovering it says: Measures (Custom Control)

Comment: After spending few hours, I found out that the "power pivot" is not a standard menu item with an idMSo. it is part of the "Application.COMAddIns" collection and called "Microsoft Power Pivot for Excel".  However, I didn't find any way to disable it or make it invisible with the ribbonX XML,  the same easy way as we would disable a Home or Data tab.  Any ideas?

Comment: In that case only the add-in vendor/developer can provide you with a public method which you may call to get the job done. There is no trivial way to disable third-party controls on the ribbon.

Comment: I was thinking about it and maybe for my issue this workaround will do it. I tried and it did what I want but I am not sure yet if there are any side effects: clear the entire ribbon, and then rebuilt their menu items. It will only affect this one document.

<ribbon startFromScratch="true">
<tabs>
<tab idMso="TabHome" visible="true"></tab>
<tab idMso="TabInsert" visible="true"></tab>
<tab idMso="TabPageLayoutExcel" visible="true"></tab>
....

Comment: Yes, there is not so much you could do with custom ribbon UI unfortunately.